# GGplot: Line in stat_summary is not being displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to have a graph showing a line connecting the dots of each group in each variable.
However it seems like ggplot refuses to render the line and I am not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(DF_Compound, aes(color=MainThemes, y=value, x=Variable)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.y="mean",
    geom="point",
    size=2,
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.y="mean",
    geom="Line",
    size=1,
  ) +
  ylim(0,9) +
  ylab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend()) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

This is the output:
[image]

This is what I would like (with a line for every Theme of course):
[image]

(Apologies for the sloppy shop on the images)

Both MainThemes and Variable are factors (if that makes any difference). If I remove the points, the coordinate system is just empty. Am I overlooking something? I've seen people add lines this way and it seems to work.

Edit:
Trying to provide data I figured out, the problem seems to be that "Variables" is a factor.
This dataset works:

```
structure(list(MainThemes = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), Variable = c(9, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 
8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 
8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 
8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 
8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4, 9, 5, 
8, 2, 3, 7, 10, 1, 6, 4), value = c(3.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
5, 3.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
5.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 1, 3.66666666666667, 
3.33333333333333, 4, 5.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
7, 6.66666666666667, 2, 4.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 2, 3.66666666666667, 2, 6.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
6, 2, 2, 2.33333333333333, 2, 4.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
5.33333333333333, 3, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2.33333333333333, 2, 4.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 3, 6, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1.33333333333333, 
4, 4.33333333333333, 4, 4.66666666666667, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
5, 5.33333333333333, 6, 4.33333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
6.66666666666667, 4, 5.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 
4.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 6, 5.66666666666667, 7, 5, 
4.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 7, 3.33333333333333, 
7, 5, 5.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4, 
2, 4.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 
6.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This one doesn't:

```
Variables are vectors:
structure(list(MainThemes = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), Variable = c("VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", 
"VA", "VF", "VD", "VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", 
"VF", "VD", "VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", 
"VD", "VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD", 
"VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD", "VI", 
"VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD", "VI", "VE", 
"VH", "VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD", "VI", "VE", "VH", 
"VB", "VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD", "VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", 
"VC", "VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD", "VI", "VE", "VH", "VB", "VC", 
"VG", "VJ", "VA", "VF", "VD"), value = c(3.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
5, 3.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
5.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 1, 3.66666666666667, 
3.33333333333333, 4, 5.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
7, 6.66666666666667, 2, 4.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 2, 3.66666666666667, 2, 6.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
6, 2, 2, 2.33333333333333, 2, 4.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
5.33333333333333, 3, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2.33333333333333, 2, 4.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 3, 6, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1.33333333333333, 
4, 4.33333333333333, 4, 4.66666666666667, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
5, 5.33333333333333, 6, 4.33333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
6.66666666666667, 4, 5.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 
4.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 6, 5.66666666666667, 7, 5, 
4.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 7, 3.33333333333333, 
7, 5, 5.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4, 
2, 4.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 
6.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Turning my variables into numbers is a workaround, but I would really like to avoid it if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Sorry, it is taking me a bit.
I had to change the Theme and Variable names for anonymisation and somehow it works with that dataset

Comment: Okay, the problem seems to be, that the Variables are vectors. If they are numbers it seems to work

Comment: Try adding `group = MainThemes` inside `aes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `MainThemes` as a grouping variable if you have a discrete x axis:

```r
DF_Compound |>
  ggplot(aes(color = MainThemes, y = value, x = Variable, group = MainThemes)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", size = 2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="Line",linewidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = 0:9, limits = c(0, 9)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

A few other points to note are:

- Since you are using `scale_y_continuous` already, then instead of using `ylab("")`, you can pass `NULL` as the first argument to `scale_y_continuous` to remove the axis label.
- `scale_fill_discrete` doesn't do anything here, since you aren't using the fill scale. However, changing it to `scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend())` won't do anything either because this is the default setting.
- The `size` argument in `geom_line` is deprecated - if your version of ggplot is up to date, you should use `linewidth` instead.
- I'm not sure that a line plot is appropriate here since you have a discrete x axis (though this is a bit domain-specific). An alternative if you want to display the relationship between two discrete variables and one continuous variables would be a heatmap. This gives a cleaner plot, though at the expense of making it a little harder to discern the exact `value`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF_Compound %>%
  group_by(MainThemes, Variable) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = MainThemes, x = Variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

If you have the space to do it, you could even get a better idea of the range of your data by using faceted boxplots or violin plots:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF_Compound %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = value, x = Variable, fill = MainThemes)) +
  geom_point(size = 1, shape = 21) +
  geom_violin(linewidth = 0.3) +
  facet_grid(MainThemes~.) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]